# resolve url in bound data

Tags: asp.net

i want to show a menu in some pages.

the menu is build from db with repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="mainMenu" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <ul>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li><a href="<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl((string)Eval("TD_PageName"))%>"><%# Eval("TD_Name")%></a></li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </ul>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

when i am in "folder/page1.aspx" all the link are ok ("http://localhost/folder/folder2/page1.aspx").  when i'm in a folder "folder/folder2/page1.aspx" the links are "http://localhost/folder/folder2/folder2/page1.aspx"

UPDATED:
i change it to

```
<a href="<%# VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/admin/"+(string)Eval("TD_PageName"))%>"><%# Eval("TD_Name")%></a>
```

Comment: Can you check what you've written in the explanation with folder and folder2 as it currently doesn't seem consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need an "/" in the beginning of your URL to make it absolute.

```
<a href="/<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl((string)Eval("TD_PageName"))%>"><%# Eval("TD_Name")%></a>
```

Comment: worked great, just edit "Page.ResolveClientUrl" for "ResolveClientUrl"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the above code is correct, but you are stating that all pages exist in "http://localhost/folder/folder2/" which doesn't match up with what you're trying to find.

folder/page.aspx = **folder/folder2/** page1.aspx

folder/folder2/page1.aspx = **folder/folder2/folder2/** page1.aspx

It looks like it's referencing properly, but if you are saying they are not, you may not have the correct URL stored in the database.

Edit: The information you are providing, still isn't very clear on what the expected behaviour is and where your error is occuring.